# PL/pgSQL - Pass Dynamic Column Name to PREPARE

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

Postgres version: 14

I have a script that does a number of small repetitive dynamic queries. This works, but it is slow, so I am converting them to prepared statements. This also works until I try to pass a column name as an argument at which point everything seems to be a syntax or "operator does not exist" error. What is the correct syntax to get this to work as shown here https://dev.to/aws-heroes/postgresql-prepared-statements-in-pl-pgsql-jl3 ?

```
DO
$$
BEGIN
    DECLARE rtmp1 record;   
    DECLARE rtmp2 record;   
    DECLARE rtmp3 record;   
    DECLARE col_name1 text := 'my_field1';
    DECLARE col_name2 text := 'my_field2';
    DECLARE col_name3 text := 'my_field3';

    -- PREPARE QUERIES
    DEALLOCATE ALL;
    EXECUTE FORMAT('PREPARE q_test(text) AS
        SELECT
            first_name
        FROM my_table
        WHERE $1 = 0');

    EXECUTE FORMAT('EXECUTE q_test(%s)', col_name1) INTO rtmp1;
    EXECUTE FORMAT('EXECUTE q_test(%s)', col_name2) INTO rtmp2;
    EXECUTE FORMAT('EXECUTE q_test(%s)', col_name3) INTO rtmp3;
END
$$;
```

Comment: see the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN)

Comment: `' ... FROM my_table WHERE ' || quote_ident(your_argument) || ' = 0'`

Comment: I don't think this would improved performance substantially. Instead of running many small statements, you should check if you can run one (or just a few) bigger statements that do more work in a single request.

Comment: @Edouard: I did RTM. The concatenation is how I'm doing it now. The point is to get away from that.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: It's an iterative and fidgety process, so I can't really lump the work together. The example I gave is just a simple expression of the problem without the  bulk of what's actually going on in the routine. From what I read, the time savings comes from using prepare to allowing the optimizer to work in a way that it can't with a concatenated query. 
See https://dev.to/aws-heroes/postgresql-prepared-statements-in-pl-pgsql-jl3

Comment: If you had read the manual you would have seen and understood this: `EXECUTE format('SELECT count(*) FROM %I ' 'WHERE inserted_by = $1 AND inserted <= $2', tabname   INTO c   USING checked_user, checked_date;` from here [Dynamic query](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN). The `format` part being further explained here [format](And from here [format](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT)  ).

Comment: @AdrianKlaver: I still can't find a syntax that works using prepare, as shown in my example. Execute is not the problem. I can execute. The problem is preparing the query. None of the examples on the man pages use prepare and I can't find a combination that works.

Comment: I can get the function to run, see my answer. Not sure what you want to do after that?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver: Your example does not include the PREPARE with the syntax that allows it to be prepared and then called repeatedly as shown here. https://dev.to/aws-heroes/postgresql-prepared-statements-in-pl-pgsql-jl3   I can get this technique to work as long as I am passing in arguments used on the right side of the operator. When I need to pass in a column name, the PREPARE starts throwing errors of various kinds.

Comment: I edited the question to show how this is meant to be able to be called once prepared. This is working fine as long as the arguments are not used as column names.

Comment: Your example will fail on general principles since you have not declared  `col_name*` or `rtmp*`. If you want a complete answer you will need to provide a complete example.

Comment: OK, I added the declarations

Comment: Are you trying to have the `col_name*` be the the `$1`?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver: Yes, exactly. This works fine when the arguments are used in other ways.

Comment: You cannot use the `$*` parameter for identifiers. `$*` can only be used for values e,g `some_fld = $1`. Do this with identifiers you either need to string concatenation or using `format`.

Comment: I was hoping there was a clever workaround. Ah well.

Comment: See  UPDATE to my answer for a different way to do this.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver: Thanks for the update. That's what I'm already doing, which works. I was trying to convert to using prepare because there is a speed benefit, per the article I linked. Using prepare is the goal. I was able to convert one query, which does not need a variable column name and did indeed get a speed boost, but it looks like the rest of the queries will have to remain slow.

Comment: 1) The article does not have a solution for dynamic column names with `PREPARE/EXECUTE` so there is no speed benefit shown for that case. 2) The speed increase was for a static query with variable values, which you would expect. 3) Read [PREPARE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-prepare.html) *NOTES*.  Per that I would not expect  a speed improvement with dynamic column names  as you are constantly changing the plan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can get the function to run:

```
\d my_table 
                           Table "public.my_table"
    Column    |            Type             | Collation | Nullable | Default 
--------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 other_column | character varying(100)      |           |          | 
 updated_at   | timestamp without time zone |           |          | 
 new_colum    | character varying(100)      |           |          | 
 first_name   | character varying           |           |          | 
 id           | integer                     |    

DO          
$$
BEGIN

    -- PREPARE QUERIES
    DEALLOCATE ALL;
    EXECUTE FORMAT('PREPARE q_test(text) AS
        SELECT
            first_name
        FROM my_table
        WHERE %I = 0', 'id');
END
$$;
```

**UPDATE**.

A version of function that iterates over field names and executes the query for each field name. Does away with the `PREPARE/EXECUTE`.

```
DO
$$
DECLARE
   fld_name text;
BEGIN

    FOREACH fld_name IN ARRAY array['id', 'first_name'] LOOP
        RAISE NOTICE '%', fld_name;
        EXECUTE FORMAT('SELECT
            first_name
        FROM my_table
        WHERE %I IS NOT NULL', fld_name);
    END LOOP;
END
$$;

NOTICE:  id
NOTICE:  first_name
DO
```

Comment: I edited my question to show how this is meant to be called so you can see why I can't embed the column name in the original prepare. I need to be able to pass it in as an argument. I am trying to do this: https://dev.to/aws-heroes/postgresql-prepared-statements-in-pl-pgsql-jl3